# Cron job is not running on Linux

Tags: linux, cron

At first, this is not exactly a programming question and more specific to Linux. I hope that it can be answered here though.

I have created a cron job which will execute a shell script every 2 minutes on my machine. However, the cronjob is not executing.

output of crontab -e command

```
2 * * * * /home/yuri/connector.sh >> /home/yuri/test.txt 2>&1
```

I have the cron daemon running:

```
ps aux | grep cron

root       944  0.0  0.0  19120   932 ?        Ss   08:25   0:02 cron
1000     19619  0.0  0.0  13600   880 pts/2    S+   21:50   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

The connector.sh shell script runs properly when I execute it manually, however when run through the cron job created above, it does not work.

I have redirected the output to a text file to know if something is going wrong while executing the cron job, but no such text file is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cron job isn't set to run every two minutes, it's set to run on the second minute of every hour.  You might change it as follows:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/yuri/connector.sh >> /home/yuri/test.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

Running every 2 minutes should be given as

```
*/2 * * * * /home/yuri/connector.sh >> /home/yuri/test.txt 2>&1.
```

Does this work ?